# JBoss 6 Web App Deployment Error

Tags: eclipse, jboss

I'm trying to set up a development environment to work on an existing web application, but can't seem to be able to deploy the war file through JBoss. I'm fairly certain that I have accurately duplicated the technologies on the production environment, but unfortunately I don't have access to it to do a back-to-back comparison. I'm using Eclipse with the JBoss tools plugin to generate a JBoss 6 optimized version of a war. Here is my error output:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/newyork" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/C:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_6.x_Runtime_Server1353365065325/deploy/newyork.war/ deployment failed

        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.client.upload.StreamingDeploymentTarget.invoke(StreamingDeploymentTarget.java:320)
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.client.upload.StreamingDeploymentTarget.start(StreamingDeploymentTarget.java:197)
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.client.upload.DeploymentProgressImpl.start(DeploymentProgressImpl.java:232)
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.client.upload.DeploymentProgressImpl.run(DeploymentProgressImpl.java:89)
        at org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.util.DeploymentUtils.run(DeploymentUtils.java:155)
        at org.rhq.plugins.jbossas5.AbstractManagedDeploymentComponent.invokeOperation(AbstractManagedDeploymentComponent.java:162)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.rhq.core.pc.inventory.ResourceContainer$ComponentInvocationThread.call(ResourceContainer.java:525)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/newyork" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/C:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_6.x_Runtime_Server1353365065325/deploy/newyork.war/ deployment failed

        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1370)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1316)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:968)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.checkComplete(MainDeployerPlugin.java:82)
        at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.checkComplete(ProfileControllerContext.java:138)
        at org.jboss.profileservice.plugins.deploy.actions.DeploymentStartAction.doPrepare(DeploymentStartAction.java:104)
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.prepare(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:101)
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.ModificationSession.prepare(ModificationSession.java:87)
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.internalPerfom(AbstractActionController.java:234)
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.performWrite(AbstractActionController.java:213)
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:150)
        at org.jboss.profileservice.plugins.deploy.AbstractDeployHandler.startDeployments(AbstractDeployHandler.java:168)
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.remoting.DeployHandlerDelegate.startDeployments(DeployHandlerDelegate.java:74)
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.remoting.DeployHandler.invoke(DeployHandler.java:156)
        at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:898)
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.local.LocalClientInvoker.invoke(LocalClientInvoker.java:106)
        at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:1961)
        at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:804)
        at org.jboss.profileservice.management.client.upload.StreamingDeploymentTarget.invoke(StreamingDeploymentTarget.java:312)
        ... 15 more
```

Comment: everywhere it is saying (see previous errors for details) can you post the complete stack trace?

Comment: Good call, I would have guessed that the relevant information was in the top of the stack. It turns out that this is a JDBC issue, I'll update the question.

Comment: haha.. sure.. leave me a tagged comment once u do